# How can get position of product in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am getting all products with their categories, below the code I am using but I want to get position of products .
I am not getting how to change my code so that it will make optimize.

```
 $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position');
              $prodIds=$products->getAllIds();
              if(count($prodIds)>0)
              {
                  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
                   $i=0;
                  foreach($prodIds as $productId)
                  {
                        $ids= array();
                        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['sku']= $productCollection ->getSku();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['product_id']= $productId;
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['name']= $productCollection ->getName();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['image']=$productCollection ->getThumbnailUrl(); 
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['description']=$productCollection ->getDescription();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['short_description']=$productCollection ->getShortDescription();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['weight']=$productCollection ->getWeight();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['created_at']=$productCollection ->getCreatedAt();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['updated_at']=$productCollection ->getUpdatedAt();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['price']=$productCollection ->getPrice();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['special_price']=$productCollection ->getSpecialPrice();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['tax_class_id']=$productCollection ->getTaxClassId();
                        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['cat_id']= implode(',',$productCollection ->getCategoryIds());
                        $ids[$i]=$result[$i]['category_ids'];
                        foreach($productCollection ->getCategoryIds() as $categoryId)
                        {
                          $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
                          $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['cat_name'][$categoryId]= $category->getName();
                        }
                       $i++;
                  }
```

I want also to add position of products in  $final['prodCat_list'] variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider cleaning up that code. Anyway, below is the solution to your problem.

```
foreach($productCollection ->getCategoryIds() as $categoryId)
{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['cat_name'][$categoryId]= $category->getName();

    // new code starts here        
    $positions = $category->getProductsPosition();

    if ($positions) {
        $final['prodCat_list'][$i]['cat_name'][$categoryId]['position'] = $positions[$productId];
    }
}
```